# Angular CSS Animate ngbPopover in the currently location

Tags: css, angular, css-animations

I need to animate a popover when it appears, basically I want to add a bounce animation.

The problem is that when the animation starts it starts at a point that is not the initial or final position of the popover, so I would like to make the bounce animation be done in the same position of the element.

I tried to modify the transform-origin property but I had no result.

```
// CSS Code
// ngbPopover
ul >>> .popover {
 border: 2px #3f51b5;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3em;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3em;
 box-shadow: 3px -2px 4px #AAA;   
 animation:bounce 2s linear; 
}

@keyframes bounce{
 1%   { transform: scale(1,1);}
 10%  { transform: scale(1.1,.9)}
 30%  { transform: scale(.9,1.1) }
 50%  { transform: scale(1.05,.95)}
 57%  { transform: scale(1,1)}
 64%  { transform: scale(1,1)}
 100% { transform: scale(1,1);}
}

// HTML Code
// Here is where the ngbPopover will shows up
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"  #itemsRef="ngbPopover" 
   [ngbPopover]="popContent"  popoverTitle="Detalle OT" [ngClass]="{'list- 
   group-item-danger': !ot.ficha}" *ngFor="let ot of ordenesTrabajo; let 
   i = index">          
    OT-{{ot.codigo}}
    Ficha: {{ot.ficha}}
  </li>          
 </ul>

 //ngbPopover Content
 <ng-template #popContent><b>{{infoOT}}</b></ng-template>
```

I would like to start the animation in the same point of the popover appears.

**EDIT:**

[This is how it works now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUiHE.gif)

Comment: It would be great if you created a jsfiddle so we can play with it